# How to wait for an activity to fully load?

Tags: android

I'm making an activity where I'm planning to display a progress bar and move to a second activity after five seconds. I used Thread.sleep to do this.
Here is the code for the activity with the spinner.

```
public class WaitScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.waitscreen);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();

        try{
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spinner complete!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){

        }
        Intent i = new Intent("emergency.app.NEWACTIVITY");
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

My main activity only has a button that leads to this page on being clicked. Problem is, it displays the main activity for five seconds, then this activity very briefly and then the third activity. How do I make the thread start after WaitScreen is fully loaded? As you can see, I tried using the onStart method to do the trick. Or if you could tell me another way to introduce a five second delay, that would be helpful too!

Comment: You should **never never never** call `sleep()` on a UI thread, because it will become unresponsive. Next to that, the Android OS will kill your app if it is unresponsive for >= 5 seconds. Use a Timer or handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Handler` to post a `Runnable`, like so:

```
public class WaitScreen extends Activity {

    private Runnable task = new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spinner complete!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent("emergency.app.NEWACTIVITY");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.waitscreen);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(task, 5000);
    }
}
```

The `Runnable` `task` will execute after 5 seconds.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: I did 1000 instead of 5000 and the text never showed up :/ Do I have to add the Runnable task above onCreate?

Comment: @SiKni8 Above or below, it doesn't matter, it's just a class variable. Make sure you've got the .show() part at the end of the Toast.